Is $K^t$ complexity closed under composition
Call an increasing function $\alpha : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ reasonable if $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}, \exists_\infty n, c K^{2n}(n) \leq \alpha (n)$. Where $K^t$ is the time bounded Kolmogorov complexity and $n$ is interpreted as its binary representation in the argument of $K^{2n}(n)$. As background, any usual function is reasonable, for instance $\log^\ast$ is reasonable (this is somewhat easily shown).
Questions :
Is reasonability closed under composition ($f,g \text{ reasonable} \Rightarrow  f \circ g \text{ reasonable}$)? Closed under application of standard function (e.g. $f \text{ reasonable} \Rightarrow  \log(f) \text{ reasonable}$)?
 I suspect the answer to be no because of the arbitrary constant $2$ in $K^{2n}$, and by taking $f=g=K^{1.9n}(n)$. 
If we change the definition to $\alpha : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ reasonable iff $\exists d\in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists_\infty n$, $cK^{dn}(n) \leq \alpha (n)$, is it now closed under composition?  $\rightarrow$ This is shown to be an equivalent question.
Notation : $\exists_\infty n, A(n)$ means that A(n) is true for infinitely many $n$.
Edit : As pointed out by Nicholas Brandt functions must be increasing or $f \circ g$ may not be reasonable.
Under this definition we may show the following :
Def : Call an increasing function $\alpha$ d-reasonable if $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}, \exists_\infty n, c K^{dn}(n) \leq \alpha (n)$.
Def : Call an increasing function $\alpha$ ultrareasonable if $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}, \exists_\infty n, c K^{1.1 \log(n)}(n) \leq \alpha (n)$.
Theorem : $\exists d, \alpha$ d-reasonable $\Leftrightarrow \alpha$ reasonable $\Leftrightarrow \alpha $ ultrareasonable

I'm confused. Do you have a proof that the answer to the first question is "no", or not?

$K^{2n}$ should be $K^{cn}$?

What is "Kolmogorov temporal complexity"? You mean time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity?

@mathworker21 no i do not have a proof, actually i now suspect that it holds

@MartinBerger No i mean $K^{2n}$ in the first definition (or $K^{en}$ if you want but the e should be fixed like e=15 or something). Yes I mean time bounded Kolmogorov complexity

@ULechine In that case, what's the point of the initial $\forall c  \in \mathbb{N}$ quantification?

@MartinBerger I realized my mistake, I added $c$ at the correct place

Your reasonable functions are not closed under composition.
Take the reasonable functions $f(n):=(n \mod 2) \cdot n$ and $g(n):=2n$.
Then $f \circ g \equiv 0$ is not reasonable.
To remedy this domain-splitting issue, one could use an $S$-reasonable notion such that $\exists_\infty n$ is replaced by $\forall n \in S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, and then require $f$ and $g$ to be reasonable for the same $S$.
As for the application of "standard" functions, I think it holds if the function $s$ can be computed uniformly and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} s(f(n))=\infty$ where $s$ is the standard function.

Thanks for the counter example, i guess to make things interesting I should have added that $\alpha$ should be increasing. I'll change the question to reflect that
